# Maharal a Mashal to the female Jewish spouse

Tags: women, allegory-mashal, maharal

I'm not sure if the Maharal says this per se but I heard a beautiful *mashal* on the woman: when this object or matter changes shape the outer object or matter changes to that shape and so on. The inner object represents the woman and the outer shape represents the man. I was wondering where it's from and if it is from the Maharal, where does he say it?

Comment: Hey Max, welcome to Mi Yodeya! ....I'm having some trouble understanding your question, particularly with regards to the exact idea you're trying to find in the Maharal....can you elaborate a bit more on that idea?

Comment: Also, you might consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 5):

The idea that you are referring to is called "Chomer" and "Tzurah" and is a recurring theme in the philosophy of the Maharal that extends beyond the mashal of man/woman.

> The Maharal (**Gur Aryeh, Devarim: 25:18**) relates that all of creation
>   is built in two complementary systems - Tzurah and Chomer. Tzurah is
>   the influential force, providing a general direction and a general
>   outline, or form. Chomer is the force that takes this influence and
>   uses it to give form to matter, to put things in the proper place and
>   composition.
>
> For instance, Bereishit Bara Elokim Et Hashamayim Ve'et Ha'aretz. This
>   is the first pair of complementary forces. Shamayim is the influential
>   - the Tzurah. It provides a general form and direction. It provides the rain, and it envelopes all of creation. Aretz is the receiver of
>   the influence. It receives the rain and uses it to bring forth
>   vegetation, crops and minerals - the Chomer of the world.
>
> In the same way, Zachar and Nekevah are complementary forces. The
>   Zachar, the male, represents the "Tzurah" - the influential force that
>   provides a general form and direction, while the Nekevah, the female,
>   receives that influence and uses it to provide substance through
>   birth, raising children, and providing the family with its needs. The
>   woman takes the influence of the man and brings it into practice and
>   fruition.

(English explanation courtesy of [Ramat Shilo](http://www.ramatshilo.org/hebrew/torah/view.asp?id=30))

Comment: Thanks for that.....it was unclear who said all that stuff in the blockquotes.....if you hadn't put it in blockquotes, I would have thought that it was you ;)

Comment: Isn't this the opposite of what the OP described?  He described the man as being the outer shape that responds to the woman.  The Maharal is describing the other way around.

Comment: @YEZ the OP didn't seem to clear on what exactly he heard. However the idea of one effecting the other reminded me of the concept of Chomer/Tzura that is so prevalent in the Maharal's works. If the OP comes back and says that that's not it or provides more details we will try again